# ¿Como generar un archivo csv a partir de una lista?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hola tengo la siguiente lista

```
  l=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
```

y quiero generar un archivo csv  algo así:

```
1 5
2 6
3 7
4 8
```

el código que he trabajado es este

```
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerows(l)
```

pero lo que hace es generarme un archivo csv de esta forma:

1,2,3,4

5,6,7,8

y lo que realmente quiero es que cada sublista sea una columna del archivo csv
ya he mirado varios ejemplos pero ninguno me aclara la duda. espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mejor es que utilices NumPy para poder *trasponer* los datos cómodamente y luego escribirlos en un CSV:

```
import numpy as np

l=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
datos = np.asarray(l)
np.savetxt("output.csv",   # Archivo de salida
           datos.T,        # Trasponemos los datos
           fmt="%d",       # Usamos números enteros
           delimiter=",")  # Para que sea un CSV de verdad
```

Answer (score 3):

Lo que necesitas es *entrelazar* las sublistas antes de enviarlas al fichero CSV. Se hace con la función `zip` y pasando la lista :

```
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerows(zip(*l))
```

En python2 la función `zip` crear una nueva lista en memoria, no como en python3 que crear un iterador. Si vas a guardar muchos datos, es más eficiente que user `itertools.izip`:

```
import itertools

with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
      writer = csv.writer(f)
      writer.writerows(itertools.izip(*l))
```

Answer (score 0):

Por si alguien anda buscando solución para el mismo caso pero en `python3`, lo pueden resolver de manera más sencilla con `pandas`, manipulando la lista como un `pandas.DataFrame()`.

> Primero importamos la librería `pandas` y después declaramos la lista que se necesita procesar:

```
import pandas as pd

l = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
```

> Luego generamos un `DataFrame` de `pandas` a partir de la lista `l` y a continuación lo trasponemos como especifica el requerimiento:

```
l_df = pd.DataFrame(l)
l_df = l_df.transpose(l_df)
```

> Podemos resumir estas dos líneas de código en una sola obteniendo el mismo resultado de la siguiente manera:

```
l_df = pd.DataFrame(l).transpose()
```

> Una ves que tenemos nuestro `pandas` generado y transpuesto veremos algo como esto:

```
In [24]: l_df                                                                   
Out[24]: 
   0  1
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7
3  4  8
```

> Por defecto, `pandas` agrega *índices de línea* y *cabeceras de columna* cuando se generan `DataFrames` de esta forma. Nos podemos deshacer de esos decoradores asignando el valor `False` a los atributos `index` y `header` del metodo `to_scv()` al momento de guardar el `DataFrame` `l_df` en un documento `csv` de la siguiente forma:

```
l_df.to_csv("archivo.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

> Comprobamos el contenido del fichero y veremos la listra `l` transpuesta, sin *índices de línea* ni *cabeceras de columna* y con los valores separados por `,`, como es la característica del formato `*.csv`

```
In [11]: cat archivo.csv                                                       
1,5
2,6
3,7
4,8
```

En resumen, la versión final de script quedaría como se ve a continuación

```
import pandas pd

l = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]

l_df = pd.DataFrame(l).transpose()
l_df.to_csv("archivo.csv", index=False, header=False)
```